# App won't display on market for HTC Sensation

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app that seems downloadable to all phones except the HTC Sensation.  My friend with the Sensation also has 2 other phones (of a lower SDK type) that he is able to install to.  I can't figure out for the life of me why.  I'm trying to get my hands on another 2.3 or above phone to see if its an issue with gingerbread.  Here are the relevant parts of my AndroidManifest (only the activities are excluded):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="x.x.x.x"
      android:versionCode="8" android:versionName="1.3.3">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <activity items.... />
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
</manifest>
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Have you checked its availability on the developer dashboard. Select your app and scroll right down to the "this app is available on so and so many devices," from there you can check if the sensation is there or not... if you haven't done that already of course =P

Comment: ^ in addition to this did you just release it? sometimes when you just update/release your app it won't show for a few hours

Comment: I'm not to sure but HTC have had some security problems recently maybe they've locked down some of the permissions temporarily.

Comment: @Jack, I have no exclusions, but I was reading about that security issue and I wonder if that's the problem.  It does work on my HTC Aria, though... also he is able to download other applications that use that ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission.

Comment: @Kevin I released the app and it has been on the market for several months.

Comment: Same problem here, would love an answer. I have the following in my manifest:
`<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                    android:normalScreens="true"
                    android:largeScreens="true"
                    android:xlargeScreens="true" /> `

Comment: @combatdave, thanks for putting a bounty up, I was about to do the same.  As of today it's still an issue with my application.

Comment: Is your friends' HTC Sensation connected to the same Google account as their other 2 phones?

Comment: Does he have a prototype of the sensation or some other reason that the device is missing the telephone hardware (or the system is reporting that its available)?

Comment: @combatdave (or John): What are the package names for your apps? I might be able to do some digging on my end to see what's going on here.

Comment: @Trevor my package is com.johnleehey.android.quicktextpro.  Its a paid app, but just let me know if you can see anything wrong.  And yes, the same account is linked to all his phones.

Comment: @John: I've tried downloading your program on an HTC Sensation. I didn't have any problems finding it in Market or installing it.

Comment: Just wondering whether you released the app to the global market or excluded soms regions? We once ran into a similar problem with a device imported from the US. I remember playing around with a piece of code to change the (semi-hardwired)'region code', but ended up never resolving the issue. Bottom line is: you might want to have a further look into the Sensation's configuration. Also, have you tried finding it on the market while being logged in with a different account on the phone?

Comment: I'm having this issue with a customer who has an HTC Vivid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing a `<supports-screen>` element in your manifest?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

I had the same problem before where I couldn't even download my own app ;__;

Joe

Comment: I wish it worked, but the `<support-screen>` element doesn't help :-/

Comment: Your friend's devices may be cached. Try clearing Android Market's cache on them devices and try again. Other than that, contact Android Market

Answer (score 0):

For fun try to add:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

These kinds of bugs can be hard to solve ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have a Sensation and my app shows in Market for my phone.  Here's my `<supports-screens>` entry:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

... and that's it.  Works fine.  If that doesn't work for you, there's something else going on.